# POSIX threads - do something only once

Tags: c, pthreads

What's the simplest way of ensuring that a region of code can only be executed by one pthread ?

Assume there are `n` threads (`n` not equal to 1)

```
// do this once
int x;
x = some_function(); 
printf( "%d\n", x );
```

Do I use a shared variable and a barrier ?  Let all variables assign their thread ID (?) to a shared variable and then the last thread to write to the variable could be the master thread ?  Then later on in the program you can check the thread ID against the shared variable ?

Many thanks.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the pthread_once() function.  It's made for this express purpose.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_once.html

You would use a shared variable to store the result.  To ensure the variable is stable, you can wrap the pthread_once() with a mutex.  All threads would need to lock and unlock the mutex while most would do nothing in the middle, but this way would ensure that the variable is fully updated before any thread is allowed to continue.

Comment: How do I get the return value of a function that I want to be called once ?  I'll edit the question to be clear ... Thanks :).

Comment: The [man](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_once.html) says: _The first call to pthread_once()... shall call the init_routine with no arguments. Subsequent calls of pthread_once() with the same once_control shall not call the init_routine._

**Is necessary to _wrap the pthread_once() with a mutex_?**